# value '0' should not accept in the date input field in react js

Tags: regex, reactjs, validation

Hi all I am doing date input validations. So that I don't want to accept number 0 only in the day and month and year field.

My date input format is `dd mm yyyy` all three will separate input components.

here is what I tried for stop two zeros

```
// validation day 
export function dayValidation(str) {
  if(str.search(/^00/) !== -1){
    return "0"; 
  }    
  return extract(str, '^([0-2]?[0-9]|3[01]|10|20)$');
}

// validation month 
export function monthValidation(str) {
  if(str.search(/^00/) !== -1){
    return "0"; 
  } 
  return extract(str, '^([0-1]?[0-2]|0[1-9]|[0-9])$');
}

export function yearValidation(str) {
  if(str.search(/^0/) !== -1){
    return ""; 
  } 
  return extract(str, '[0-9]+');

}
```

its working fine for do not entering two 00 digits. but I want to show error if the value will be only 0.

here is what I tried for validation:

```
if (Validator.isEmpty(data.applyStartYear)) {
    errors.applyStartYear = APPLY_START_DATE;
  }

  if (Validator.isEmpty(data.applyEndYear)) {
    errors.applyEndYear = APPLY_END_DATE;
  }

  if(!dateValidation(`${data.applyStartDay}-${data.applyStartMonth}-${data.applyStartYear}`, `${data.applyEndDay}-${data.applyEndMonth}-${data.applyEndYear}`) && !Validator.isEmpty(data.applyEndYear)){
    errors.applyEndYear = DATE_MISMATCH;
  }
```

so how to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of input are we talking about here? Could you use a date type?

Comment: not sure, but think that maybe the string coming may be *0* instead of *00*.
Anyway, I'd use the *^0+$* regex to check if the string start and finish with only zeros.

Comment: @Dale its just a normal input field

Comment: @LeonardoMaffei then i should return ^0+$ instead of 0 isn't?